# How to only remove stopwords when they are not nouns?

Tags: solr, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm using Solr 5 and need to remove stop words to prevent over-matching and avoid bloating the index with high IDF terms. However, the corpus includes a lot part numbers and name initials like "Steve A" and "123-OR-A". In those cases, I don't want "A" and "OR" to get removed by the stopword filter factory as they need to be searchable.

The [Stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) does a great job detecting that the above examples are nouns, not stop words, but is this the right approach for solving my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you can decide whether this is the right approach. If you can integrate POS tagger in and it gives you useful results - that's good.

But just to give you an alternative, you could look at duplicating your fields and processing them differently. For example, if you see **123-OR-A** being split and stopword-cleaned, that probably means you have [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#WordDelimiterFilterFactory) in your analyzer stack. That factory has a lot of parameters you could try tweaking. Or, you could **copyField** your content to another (**store=false**) field and process it without WordDelimiterFilterFactory all together. Then you search over both copies of your data, possibly with different boost for different fields.